# Use a directory from RPM as a parameter for different tool

Tags: rpm, java, cpio

I have a need to fetch a folder from an **RPM** package that contains number of **.jar** files. My idea was that maybe it would be possible to pass it in a stream to **java -cp** command as classpath for it?

The project that I am working on builds 10+ big RPM's and for each of them I need to execute a certain program against it that needs the classpath of the application residing in the RPM.

I stumbled upon a tool called **rpm2cpio** which can be piped to **cpio** command. But now my knowledge is getting thin. I am not sure if it is possible to not extract the contents of the cpio package to disk but instead use a file stream from it, filter a certain folder out and use that as a parameter to another command?

Why I am even trying this is simply because extracting the **whole** thing on disk will be a IO heavy operation which I would gladly avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rpm -qlp package.rpm
```

will list the files contained in `package.rpm` without extracting it in its entirety, and should be fast enough even on large RPMs. Using that list of files, you should the' be able to build the classpath you’re after.

To extract a specific directory from an RPM, with all its contents, you need to create the directory, then use `cpio` to extract the relevant files from the RPM:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir ./the/requested/directory
rpm2cpio /path/to/the/package.rpm | cpio -i ./the/requested/directory/\*
```

Comment: But this would still probably mean that the ones that I need for the classpath need to extracted right? As the files printed out by the command will be shown with locations that indicate where they will reside when RPM is installed on system.

Comment: Ah, OK, so really what you’re after is *extracting* a specific directory and its contents from an RPM, right?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be fairly acceptable solution. Thank you!